# Android intent-filter SET_ALARM no longer works?

Tags: android, google-search, google-now, google-voice

Until recently, this manifest declaration allowed my app to be listed as provider for alarms in response to voice commands (i.e. "set timer for 5 minutes"):

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_ALARM"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

As explained here: [System Voice Actions](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/#step_1_define_an_intent_filter)

After Google I/O 2016, without notice, only Google's default Clock (deskclock) is listed. 
It's impossible to unset it from being default, and tapping the "more" button show deskclock as the only option to choose from.

But when disabling it, other timers are listed as before.
It looks like Google did something to mandate deskclock if available, and allow other timers *only* if it's not available.

[image: google hides 3rd party apps]

(I used different voice command, but the effect is the same)

logcat doesn't reveal the cause, but just the effect:

```
ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SET_TIMER pkg=com.google.android.deskclock cmp=com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.HandleApiCalls (has extras)} from uid 10024 on display 0
```

I couldn't find any mention for such change, no bug report so far.

Any information or work around would be appreciated.

Comment: Same to me. I have discovered this today. Any solution yet?

Comment: @chrisonline nothing so far AFAIK... I hope it's a bug and not intentional

Comment: @chrisonline someone has opened an issue for this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212326

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.